# Sanitization in Angular

Tags: angular-sanitizer

I have a child model that has an attribute photoPath

```js
export interface Child {
    chIld: number;
    firstName: string;
    photoPath?: string;
    
    photos: Photo[];
}
```

I am trying to sanitize the photoPath to bypass angular security

```js
export class ChildrenCardComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() children: Child;

    public imgurl: Child["photoPath"];

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { 
        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.imgurl)
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
       
    }
}
```

The path is called and assigned as seen (`public imgurl: Child["photoPath"];`) in an array

The HMTL calls the imgurl as shown below:

```
 <img [src]="imgurl >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

```
 @Input() children: Child;
  
  public imgurl: any;
  
  

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { 
   
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.imgurl=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.children.photoPath)
 
  }
```